# rviz - storing point cloud selection

Tags: rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

using the "select" tool in rviz you can easily select points from a point cloud. The selected points will then show up in the selection panel.

My question is: Is there any possibility to export this selection? E.g. store the indices in a file? Or republish them on a different topic?

The reason is I would like to manually segment a point cloud in rviz in order to provide ground truth for comparing it to a segmentation algorithm.

I believe one idea would be to write an rviz plug-in for this. But I wonder, whether somebody has already stumbled upon this problem and found an easy solution (less hacky than http://answers.ros.org/question/12806/interactively-access-to-laser-point-in-rviz/)?

Best,
Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99796/rviz---storing-point-cloud-selection/) by [sebastianh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1227/sebastianh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

finally we wrote a plugin, as there is no such feature in RVIZ. It provides a new tool that inherits all features of the default 'select' tool and additionally publishes all selected points on the ros topic '/selected_points'.

It can be found at:
https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg

---

Originally posted by [pBartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/9141/pbartels/) with karma: 76 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MSD](https://answers.ros.org/users/22587/msd/) on 2015-07-23**:
hi pBartels!
Can you share the link to your usefull plugin please? The old link is not working.

Thank you!

**Comment by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on 2015-07-30**:
You can use the following link: https://github.com/tu-rbo/turbo-ros-pkg

**Comment by [hndrk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30567/hndrk/) on 2017-10-04**:
Hi, just implemented the plugin, but crashes upon doing the selection printing some storage-access-failure in the terminal. Anybody got an idea? I'm running ROS kinetic 1.12.7
thx in advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no such direct method for point cloud selection in the RVIZ itself as far as I know.
But, there is a open source annotation tool called "LabelMe" available for labeling the point cloud.
This toolbox is created by CSAIL MIT lab and widely used by many people for providing ground truth values for segmentation problem.

[LabelMe3D Toolbox link to website](http://new-labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/browserTools/php/labelme3d_toolbox.php)

---

Originally posted by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) with karma: 311 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to the Top menu in RVIZ and click on **Panels**. Under the Panels, tick **Selection**. Once Selection is enabled, it adds a new Panel called Selection. Then on the RVIZ gui press on **select** option which is beside **Move Camera** option.

**Then whatever points you select on the point cloud will displayed in the Selection panel.**

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1